# How do I call a service in angularJs config?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that needs to be called in the app's config module but it errors when I try to inject it.  Any ideas?  FYI - this service works perfectly fine in controllers when injected and executed.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'myService', function($routeProvider, myService) {
    var controller = myService.getSomeValue() ? 'FirstController', 'SecondController';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            'templateUrl': '/myTemplate.html'
            'controller': controller
        })
});
```

> Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>       Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=myService

Comment: The AngularJS framework operates in two phases, the config phase and the run phase. Only provider config objects can be injected in the config phase. Services can only be injected during the run phase.

Comment: Also, to add to @georgeawg , if you want to trigger some service on `route` change. you can use `resolve`  property inside `.when()`. Let us know your use case

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS framework operates in two phases, the config phase and the run phase. Only provider objects can be injected in the config phase. Services can only be injected during the run phase.

From the Docs:

> ### `module.config(configFn);`
>
> Use this method to configure services by injecting their [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#provider), e.g. for adding routes to the [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).
>
> Note that **you can only inject [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#provider) and [constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant)** into this function.
>
> For more about how to configure services, see [Provider Recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS module type API Reference - config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Providers - Summary](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#conclusion)