# in angularjs trying to loop factory data to create config also ng-view not showing html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I'm trying to put my routes into a factory and then use this data to loop through to create the config routes, but it doesn't work.

An additional problem is that even when I just put in some routes the ng-view doesn't display the content from the html files?

Code is below, though I havent included the View1.html and View2.html but they can contain anything for testing.

I would very much appreciate any advice :)

Thanks

Dom

main html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="templateApp" layout="column"
    ng-controller="controller">  
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <md-button class="menu" ng-click="toggleList()">
            <i class="material-icons vertical-align-middle">menu</i>
        </md-button>
        <h3>test template</h3>
        <md-button ng-click="toggleRight()">
            Filters        
        </md-button>        
    </md-toolbar>  
    <div class="container" layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="left">
            <md-list>
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="p in pages">
                    <md-button ng-click="selectPage(p)">
                        <i class="material-icons vertical-align-middle">{{p.icon}}</i>
                        {{p.name}}
                    </md-button>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-sidenav>

        <md-content id="content" flex>
            <div><a href ="#partial1">Partial 1</a> </div>
            <div ng-view></div>     
        </md-content>

   <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">
        <md-button ng-click="close()" class="button">
          Close Filters
        </md-button>
    </md-sidenav>

    </div>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "pages.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

page.js:

```
var templateApp = angular.module('templateApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

templateApp.factory('pageFactory', function () {

    var pages = [
                {icon: 'assessment', name: 'Overview', route: '/partial1', template: 'View1.html'},
                {icon: 'assignment', name: 'Dashboard', route: '/partial2', template: 'View2.html'}
        ];

    var factory = {};
    factory.getPages = function(){
        return pages;
    }

    return factory;
});

templateApp.controller('controller', function($scope, $mdSidenav, pageFactory, $location) {

        $scope.toggleList = function () {
            $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
        };

        $scope.toggleRight = function () {
            $mdSidenav('right').toggle();
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $mdSidenav('right').close();
        };


        $scope.selectPage = function (page) {
            $location.path(page.route);
        };

        $scope.pages = pageFactory.getPages();

    });
```

```js
templateApp.config(function($routeProvider, pageFactory) {

angular.forEach(pageFactory.getPages(), function(r) {
    $routeProvider.when(r.route, {controller: 'controller', template: r.template});
});

});

//templateApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
//    $routeProvider
//    .when("/partial1", {
//        templateUrl : "View1.html"
//    })
//    .when("/partial2", {
//        templateUrl : "View2.html"
//    });
//});
```

app.css:

```
html, body {
    font-family= 'roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.vertical-align-middle { 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

md-toolbar h3 {
    margin: auto;
    font-weight:500;
}

md-list-item > button {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left !important;
}

#content {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can only inject a provider not factory or service in `config` block.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply; would you be able to advise how I might convert the factory to a provider?

Comment: Services can't be injected in config blocks. For more information, see [How do I call a service in angularJs config?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676029/5535245).

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi, what happened to the code example you provided?

Comment: I deleted it because it broke the `getPages()` in  your controller and the loop for the config still didn't work. See [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).